# Rerender not loading new records for datatable

Tags: visualforce, rerender, datatable

I am displaying custom object records in a datatable. I modify the data using the Salesforce API (i.e. outside the current page), and then when the user clicks a button I want to rerender the datatable and show the changes.

The problem I have is that the rerender does not pick up the changes, it shows the old data. Reloading the whole page does pick up the changes. Here is the code:

```
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="rerenderMyPanel" rerender="MyPanel" />
    </apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id="MyPanel" styleClass="pbBody" layout="block">
        <apex:dataTable value="{!Account.MyCustomObject__r}" var="item" styleClass="list">
            ... datatable here.

        </apex:dataTable> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

I am sure my rerender is working because I can see the table being returned in the Chrome network tab. I also know that a race condition isn't the problem because even after making multiple edits the data via the API, re-rendering doesn't pick up the changes.

I suspect the problem is that the data from `Account.MyCustomObject__r` is stored in the view state and so doesn't change in the re-render. But I can't work out how to tell Salesforce to use the data stored in the DB during the re-render.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the standard controller:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" ...>
```

When you use the standard controller, it only loads the data once, when the page first loads.

You'll need to use a different technique, such as client-side rendering (e.g. [apex:remoteObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_remoteObjects.htm)), reloading the page entirely, or writing a custom extension in Apex code.